# ANTLR function to retrieve text from a single node in a parse tree

Tags: parsing, tree, nodes, antlr4

I want to retrieve text from a parse tree's node but when i use getText(), it retrieves all the text from that node's children.
I have searched but i don't find any ANTLR function that can retrieve only the node's text or a function to delete a node's children (so that i can use getText() on that node once i have deleted his children). Any help is welcomed.

Comment: Tree node text is read only, but if you want to modify the text associated with a tree node, then you can either create a hashed mapping Map<ParseTree, String>, or you can override the base class for the parse tree in the grammar with new get/setText() so that during construction, you can do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

That would be because a “node” (and particularly, it’s text) includes it’s children.  If you define it as the text that’s not part of a child, you’re left with just to tokens (leaf nodes) in that parser rule, and that’s probably a bit less than useful (some text with holes where other rules kick in).

Maybe you have a situation where something like this would be useful.  If so, you might want to elaborate.  We might, then propose something more specific.

---

To address your comment, here's the implementation of `getText()` for [RuleContext](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/RuleContext.java)

```java
    public String getText() {
        if (getChildCount() == 0) {
            return "";
        }

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
            builder.append(getChild(i).getText());
        }

        return builder.toString();
    }
```

So, technically, the text of a node is nothing but the concatenation of the texts of it's children.  By that definition, there'd be no text of a parent that's not child text.

Perhaps the definition of children nodes you mean is "children nodes that are `RuleNode`s" (as opposed to `ErrorNode`s or `TerminalNode`s).  You *could* implement a `getText()` that ignored `ParserRuleContext`, but that would return a rather odd concatenation of tokens that could have occurred before, after, or between, your `RuleNode`s.

I don't think there's any generalized solution to what you're asking for.  You'll need to pull out the specific text you want for parent nodes context by context.

Comment: What i want to do is retrieve a node's text seperately from his children's text so i can then store them (the node's text and every one of his children's text) in different variables, to be able to have control over these different string variables which is not possible if i do getText() on the parent node (since it concatenates his text and his children's text without any special character to separate them and have control over them).